# How to show last login time as "Logged <sometime> ago" in a toolbar?

Tags: iphone, time, refresh, toolbar, last-modified

I want to show the time difference between last login time & current login time. That means, the message should be in the form like "Logged 5 mins ago". This message will be showed in a toolbar which placed in a tableview. How can i do it?

Another question is, even though i show the message, for each a minute, can i refresh the toolbar to get the updated time?

Answer (score 0):

Store the last login time in userDefaults,

Calculate the time difference by,

```
NSTimeInterval timeDiff = [loginTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
int diff=trunc(timeDiff/(60*60));
```

Display the value in toolbar

Comment: Thank you for your reply... But how to refresh the toolbar? Think user stays more time in the same screen. So we need to update the time...